# ubuntu gcc error ctype was not declared in this scope

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++

I encountered this problem today. I can compile the project using QT4 in ubuntu 12.04 yesterday, but today I find that any c++ project could not been compiled because of these errors. I have upgrade my system to the latest.

Does anyone give me some advice, please? Thank you.

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2561:50: error: ‘ctype_base’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2543:14: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_classes.tcc:107:5: note:   ‘std::use_facet’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2566:5: error: ‘isdigit’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2543:24: error: ‘ctype’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2566:5: error: template declaration of ‘bool isdigit’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2543:24: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2567:7: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2567:7: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘return’/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/localefwd.h:123:11: note:   ‘std::ctype’

/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2567:75: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2543:36: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2543:38: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2543:47: error: request for member ‘is’ in ‘__loc’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2543:50: error: ‘ctype_base’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2548:31: error: ‘locale’ does not name a type
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h: In function ‘bool isupper(_CharT, const int&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2549:14: error: ‘use_facet’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2549:14: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_classes.tcc:107:5: note:   ‘std::use_facet’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2549:24: error: ‘ctype’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2549:24: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/localefwd.h:123:11: note:   ‘std::ctype’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2549:36: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2549:38: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2549:47: error: request for member ‘is’ in ‘__loc’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2549:50: error: ‘ctype_base’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2554:31: error: ‘locale’ does not name a type
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h: In function ‘bool islower(_CharT, const int&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2555:14: error: ‘use_facet’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2555:14: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_classes.tcc:107:5: note:   ‘std::use_facet’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2555:24: error: ‘ctype’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2555:24: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/localefwd.h:123:11: note:   ‘std::ctype’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2555:36: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2555:38: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2555:47: error: request for member ‘is’ in ‘__loc’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
make[2]: *** 
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2560:31: error: ‘locale’ does not name a type
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h: In function ‘bool isalpha(_CharT, const int&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2561:14: error: ‘use_facet’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2561:14: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_classes.tcc:107:5: note:   ‘std::use_facet’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2561:24: error: ‘ctype’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2561:24: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/localefwd.h:123:11: note:   ‘std::ctype’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2561:36: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2561:38: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2561:47: error: request for member ‘is’ in ‘__loc’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2561:50: error: ‘ctype_base’ has not been declared
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h: At global scope:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2566:5: error: ‘isdigit’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2566:5: error: template declaration of ‘bool isdigit’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2567:7: error: expected primary-expression before ‘return’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2567:7: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘return’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/locale_facets.h:2567:75: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
make[2]: ***
```

Comment: Replace all `\u2018` and `\u2019` with `'` first please.

Comment: Thank you. I have replace them.

Comment: The problem is in `ctype` and `ctype_base`, what are they and where did you declare/define them? Are you sure you're trying to build the same code that built fine yesterday?

Comment: @Shark, they're part of the standard library

Comment: It looks as though you haven't correctly upgraded your system, G++ is unable to find some of its standard library header files

Comment: Absolutely the same. Because when I compile another c++ project, these errors occurred, I have debugged for a long time. So I compile the project which successfully compiled yesterday, those errors are still exist. So I think some c++ development environment has a problem. But I did not change any files in the c++ system libraries.

Comment: @Jonathan, I just: sudo apt-get update, and then sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Try uninstalling gcc and reinstalling it, it looks as though you've still got the old GCC and it can't find its headers after your upgrade.

Comment: @Jonathan, I have searched Google, there is an similar problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11416384, But the solution did not work for me.

Comment: I can't help youu - you've messed up the upgrade somehow and the solution is to reinstall some or all of the packages